# Python Pandas: Calculate how many full business days between two timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

**My goal is to calculate how many full business days there are between two timestamps.**

A "business day" in this context is a full day (24hrs) and days can be split (Ex: Friday at noon -> Monday at noon = 1 full business day)

This cannot be solved with numpy because business days must exclude Saturday, Sunday, and Holidays.
The real world problem uses a custom holiday calendar, but the snippet below is using the built-in `USFederalHolidayCalendar` for simplicity. This is why it needs to be solved with Pandas as far as I know.

Through examples online, experimentation, and reading the docs, I have this snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
from datetime import datetime

cal = CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

print(len(pd.date_range(
     start=datetime.fromisoformat('2022-10-04T00:00:00'),
     end=datetime.fromisoformat('2022-10-04T00:00:01'),
     freq=cal)))
```

The result shows: `1`

That's inaccurate in terms of the problem I need to solve. The range is actually just **1 second**, which is far from a business day.

Here are values that don't return how I would expect:

- `'2022-10-04T00:00:00' -> '2022-10-04T00:00:01'` - Expected: 0 (Actual: 1)
- `'2022-10-04T00:00:00' -> '2022-10-04T23:59:59'` - Expected: 0 (Actual: 1)
- `'2022-10-03T23:59:59' -> '2022-10-05T00:00:00'` - Expected: 1 (Actual: 2)
- `'2022-09-30T12:00:00'` -> `'2022-10-03T12:00:00'` (Friday->Monday) - Expected: 1 (Actual: 2)

**How can I get the expected results using pandas?**

*Side Note: I was trying to make it work by first calculating with `freq='1H'` and then eliminating "business days" from that result and I couldn't get anywhere with it.*

Comment: Wait, does the specification actually care about the time of day? For example, if the first timestamp is 1PM on a non-holiday weekday, and the second timestamp is on the next weekday (also not a holiday), *do we care whether* the second timestamp is before or after 1PM?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, it must be a full 24hr period. The time of day absolutely matters. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew, lots of trial and error, but I figured it out!

#### **Quick Answer + Snippet:**

The trick is that you can't use business "day" logic, you must use business "hours".

The Pandas bday logic has no concept of partial days. For this, we use `CustomBusinessHour` and calculate the days based on how many hours passed.

Note that this *still* isn't 100% accurate! See the explanation and full snippet in the next section of this answer to get full accuracy.

```
# Create a custom business hour schedule
us_bh = CustomBusinessHour(start='00:00', end='23:59', calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

# Count the hours calculated between the two times
hours = len(pd.date_range(
    start=datetime.fromisoformat('2022-10-04T00:00:00'),
    end=datetime.fromisoformat('2022-10-04T00:00:01'),
    freq=us_bh))

# Calculate number of days
bd = floor(hours / 24)
```

#### **A Caveat to This Solution:**

When defined with an end of `23:59`, `CustomBusinessHour` will count anything within the 23rd hour as a full hour (I don't know why, but it does).

To get around this, I checked if the end timestamp is within 23:00-23:59 and subtracted an hour if the start time also isn't within the 23rd hour:

```
us_bh = CustomBusinessHour(start='00:00', end='23:59', calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

start = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-10-04T00:00:00')
end = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-10-04T23:59:59')

hours = len(pd.date_range(
    start=start,
    end=end,
    freq=us_bh))

# Fix for caveat here:
if end.hour == 23 and start.hour != 23:
    hours = hours - 1
```

#### **Full Working Snippet With Test Cases:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from datetime import datetime
from math import floor
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessHour

test_cases = [
    {
      "start": '2022-10-04T00:00:00',
      "end": '2022-10-04T00:00:01',
      "expect": 0
    },
    {
      "start": '2022-10-04T00:00:00',
      "end": '2022-10-04T22:59:59',
      "expect": 0
    },
    {
      "start": '2022-10-04T00:00:00',
      "end": '2022-10-04T23:00:00',
      "expect": 0
    },
    {
      "start": '2022-10-04T00:00:00',
      "end": '2022-10-05T23:00:00',
      "expect": 1
    },
    {
      "start": '2022-10-03T23:59:59',
      "end": '2022-10-05T00:00:00',
      "expect": 1
    },
    {
      # Regular weekend
      "start": '2022-09-30T12:00:00',
      "end": '2022-10-03T12:00:00',
      "expect": 1
    },
    {
      # Regular weekend + a few minutes
      "start": '2022-09-30T12:00:00',
      "end": '2022-10-03T14:14:00',
      "expect": 1
    },
    {
      # Regular weekend
      "start": '2022-09-30T12:00:00',
      "end": '2022-10-04T12:00:00',
      "expect": 2
    },
    {
      # Christmas weekend
      "start": '2022-12-23T12:00:00',
      "end": '2022-12-26T13:00:00',
      "expect": 0
    },
    {
      # Christmas weekend + 1
      "start": '2022-12-23T12:00:00',
      "end": '2022-12-27T12:00:00',
      "expect": 1
    }
]

# Custom hour schedules
us_bh = CustomBusinessHour(start='00:00', end='23:59', calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())

for test_case in test_cases:
    start = datetime.fromisoformat(test_case['start'])
    end = datetime.fromisoformat(test_case['end'])
    expect = test_case['expect']

    # Use Pandas to calculate the number of hours using the us_bh frequency
    hours = len(pd.date_range(
        start=start,
        end=end,
        freq=us_bh))

    # CustomBusinessHour does not calculate properly if the end time is between 23:00 - 23:59
    if end.hour == 23 and start.hour != 23:
        hours = hours - 1

    # Calculate days
    bd = floor(hours / 24)

    # Debug output
    print("\nPASS" if bd == expect else "\n\n\nFAIL")
    print(f'Between {start} -> {end} it\'s been {bd} full business day(s)')
```

***Output***

```
PASS
Between 2022-10-04 00:00:00 -> 2022-10-04 00:00:01 it's been 0 full business day(s)

PASS
Between 2022-10-04 00:00:00 -> 2022-10-04 22:59:59 it's been 0 full business day(s)

PASS
Between 2022-10-04 00:00:00 -> 2022-10-04 23:00:00 it's been 0 full business day(s)

PASS
Between 2022-10-04 00:00:00 -> 2022-10-05 23:00:00 it's been 1 full business day(s)

PASS
Between 2022-10-03 23:59:59 -> 2022-10-05 00:00:00 it's been 1 full business day(s)

PASS
Between 2022-09-30 12:00:00 -> 2022-10-03 12:00:00 it's been 1 full business day(s)

PASS
Between 2022-09-30 12:00:00 -> 2022-10-03 14:14:00 it's been 1 full business day(s)

PASS
Between 2022-09-30 12:00:00 -> 2022-10-04 12:00:00 it's been 2 full business day(s)

PASS
Between 2022-11-23 12:00:00 -> 2022-11-28 12:00:00 it's been 1 full business day(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay    

start=datetime.fromisoformat('2022-10-03T23:59:59') + BDay(1)
end=datetime.fromisoformat('2022-10-05T00:00:00') + BDay(1)
days = (end-start).days
print(days.days)
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't account for weekends or holidays.

Comment: ah. right.   updated to handle weekends as per your ask...

Comment: Appreciate the input but this still doesn't account for holidays.